# Why IntelliJ is showing Dependency 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25' not found?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, slf4j

I have added slf4j dependency from mvn repository.

My pom.xml is given below after adding that dependency :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>KafkaProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

After adding this dependency in my project, it is giving an error saying that:

```
Dependency 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25' not found
```

By the way, I am using **IntelliJ IDEA**. So, how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Try again. Your network might have been temporarily down.

Comment: Make sure to reimport/enable maven autoimport.

Comment: Always run `mvn -U dependency:resolve` if you run into a problem with downloading a dependency (the `-U` means "always try to update from the server"). If the error persists, you'll get a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not giving me the error.

I think the dependencies are not downloaded due to slow network.

Try to update the project by doing **Maven Update/Install** to download the dependencies again.

Try this pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>KafkaProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>simple Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>KafkaProject</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: @VishalBarvaliya Is this helpful ?